# XPath with hiearchical matching

Tags: xpath

**  Edited for clarification **

I've inherited a bunch of xml documents (configuration files) that resemble the following structure (element names changes and structured simplified for the sake of brevity.

```
<containers>
    <container id="c1">
        <ports>
            <port id="p2"/>
        </ports>
        <rules>
            <!--
              Within a container, a rule must refer to a port
              declared within the same container.
              A rule cannot refer to a port that does not
              exist in the enclosing container.
            -->
            <rule id="r1" portId="p1"/><!-- p1 is not in c1, but in c2, bad -->
            <rule id="r2" portId="p2"/><!-- this is good -->
            <rule id="r3" portId="p3"/><!-- p3 is nowhere, bad -->
        </rules>
    </container>
    <container id="c2">
        <ports>
            <port id="p1"/>
            <port id="p2"/>
        </ports>
        <rules>
            <rule id="r1" portId="p1"/>
        </rules>
    </container>
</containers>
```

A container can have points and rules (point and rule ids can be duplicated among containers; they just need to be unique within a container.)

The requirement is that if a rule references a point id, that point id must be defined within the enclosing container.

I need to search for rules within containers that, by mistake reference non-existing points.

I have xpath expressions that can find a rule that points to a non-existing point (unfortunately for the entire xml document.)

```
//*/rule/@portId[not( . =  //*/port/@id)]
```

The rule applies to the entire document, it is not contained within containers.

That is, this xpath expression would detect that the rule r3 in container c1 refers to a port p3 that does not exist anywhere in the document.

However, this same xpath expression would *not* detect that rule r1 in container c1 refers to a port p2 that is not in container c1. Why? Because this xpath expression will match it with port p2 in container c2.

***My xpath expression would not detect this.***

Granted, I could do this with several xpath expressions and glue code between them (say, by applying the  xpath expression to each container) but I was hoping if it is possible to use one single xpath expression starting from the root element instead.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option using the `ancestor::` axis...

```
//rule[not(@portId = ancestor::container//port/@id)]
```

Comment: I love the compactness of it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.

```
//rule[@portId[not(. =  ./parent::rule/parent::rules/parent::container/*/port/@id)]]
```

This seems to work for me. Tested on:

```
<containers>
    <container id="c1">
        <ports>
            <port id="p2"/>
            <port id="p4"/>
        </ports>
        <rules>
            <!--
              Within a container, a rule must refer to a port
              declared within the same container.
              A rule cannot refer to a port that does not
              exist in the enclosing container.
            -->
            <rule id="r1" portId="p1"/><!-- p1 is not in c1, but in c2, bad -->
            <rule id="r2" portId="p2"/><!-- this is good -->
            <rule id="r3" portId="p3"/><!-- p3 is nowhere, bad -->
        </rules>
    </container>
    <container id="c2">
        <ports>
            <port id="p1"/>
            <port id="p2"/>
        </ports>
        <rules>
            <rule id="r1" portId="p1"/>
            <rule id="r2" portId="p4"/>
        </rules>
    </container>
</containers>
```

using [this online processor](https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html).

Got the following output

```
Element='<rule id="r1" portId="p1"/>'
Element='<rule id="r3" portId="p3"/>'
Element='<rule id="r2" portId="p4"/>'
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort you put in the answer. I love it, but I think I'm going to select Daniel's answer since it seems shorter. Either way, both answers have given me a good example on how to use these axis. Thanks.

Comment: @luis.espinal I lika that answer as well and give it a vote up :)